# React fetch from Go/Golang server parsing data in unexpected JSON format to number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, go, fetch-api

I am constructing a web application which uses a Go server to serve data to a React app.

In the construction of my server, I followed the tutorial provided by Go docs (https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin). My code is very similar to that code, and I get the expected results when I use *curl*.

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "date":"2021-11-21T12:00:00Z",
    "rentedTo":"Bob",
    "rentedBy":"Jim"
  },
  //etc...
```

When I use React's fetch API, however, my results come back in an unexpected form.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/rentals')
.then((response)=> {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw response;
.then((jsonArr) => {
  handleRentalsData(jsonArr)
  })
.catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
});
```

When I `console.log(jsonArr)`, the browser reports the following:

```
Array(3) [ {...},{...},{...} ]
//Expanding this object via the console shows the following information:
---> 0: Object { id: 0, date: "2021-11-21T12:00:00Z", rentedTo: "Bob", ... } 
---> 1: Object { id: 1, date: "2021-11-22T12:00:00Z", rentedTo: "Bob", ... }
---> 2: Object { id: 2, date: "2021-11-23T12:00:00Z", rentedTo: "Bob", ... }
```

These indices (and the browser's label) indicated that the data was now in the form of an Array, so I treated it as such.

I attempted to loop through this array to parse the json strings inside of it, but `JSON.parse(data)` produces only numbers (0, 1, and 2 respectively) rather than producing objects, as I expected it to.

```
for (const json in jsonArr){
  console.log(typeof json);            //string
  const rentalObj = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(typeof rentalObj);       //number
  console.log(rentalObj);              //0, 1, and 2 respectively
  console.log(rentalObj.date);         //undefined, because rentalObj is now a number.
}
```

I have done some searching, and have heard that the indices of the array the data came in may be causing an issue, so I tried to parse with a reviver function, as well.

```
for (const json in jsonArr){
  console.log(typeof json);            //string
  const rentalObj = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
    console.log(key);                  //<empty string>
    console.log(value);                //0, 1, and 2
    return(value);
  });
  console.log(typeof rentalObj);       //number
  console.log(rentalObj);              //0, 1, and 2 respectively
  console.log(rentalObj.date);         //undefined
}
```

Attempting to `JSON.parse(jsonArr)` throws an error, as expected. I'm stumped. Why does it parse into a(n index) number? How can I extract the Objects inside of the Array, when parsing (or printing) the strings inside of the array produces only numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json` value in `for (const json in jsonArr) {` will be set to the "enumerable properties" of the `jsonArr` Array, which, in this case, are the indexes.

```js
for (const x in ['foo','bar','baz']) { console.log(x) };
// output:
// 0
// 1
// 2
```

So you probably don't want to use `for ... in`. Instead you can use `for ... of` to iterate over the elements of the array:

```js
for (const x of ['foo','bar','baz']) { console.log(x) };
// output:
// foo
// bar
// baz
```

[Array iteration and `for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in):

> **Note:** `for...in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.
>
> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
> are otherwise identical to general object properties. There is no
> guarantee that `for...in` will return the indexes in any particular
> order. The `for...in` loop statement will return all enumerable
> properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
> inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation-dependent, iterating
> over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore,
> it is better to use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop with a numeric index (or
> [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop) when iterating over
> arrays where the order of access is important.